# Uncaught Syntax error: unexpected end of input line: 78

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making a program to draw with circles, its giving me the same syntax error everytime I run it. It seems it should be perfectly fine, but it isnt. Heres the code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
  <title> Circle draw</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  canvas{
    
    border: 1px solid black;
    
  }
  
  body{
    
    margin: 0;
    
  }
  
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="result1"></div>
  <div id="result2"></div>
  <div id="result3"></div>
  <canvas>
    
    
  </canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
  window.onload = function(){
    window.onclick = function(e){
      var evt = window.event||e;
      document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "you made a circle at coordinates: "
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = evt.clientX;
  document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = evt.clientY}
  
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
  
 var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
  

  var radius = 50;
  var dx = 5;
  var dy = 5;
  c.beginPath();
  c.stroke();
  function animate() { 
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    
    
    var x = document.getElementById(resulet2);
    var y = document.getElementById(resulet3);
   c.beginPath(); 
    c.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI * 2,false);
  c.stroke();
    
  x += dx
  y += dy
    
    
    if( x + radius > canvas.width || x - radius < 0){ dx = -dx}
      
      
     if( y + radius > canvas.height || y - radius < 0){ dy = -dy}
 
  }
  
  animate();
    
    
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

That's the code, but I said all that's possible about it and I need more details so I'm just gonna talk about what should happen when the code runs. It should spawn a circle where you click or tap, then move it without clearing the other circles and bounce off walls.

Comment: You are missing a closing curly brace (`}`) in your `onload` event listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three functions, you are only ending two. Just add another function end `}`, and you should be fine.